# eval в delphi

Tags: delphi

Есть ли аналог в delphi функции eval которая может считать, например, `(2+6)*7+55/6`?

Answer (score 1):

В стандартной поставке - нет. С помощью дополнительных компонентов - да. Например, используя TEvaluator из [JEDI Code Library](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/index.php?title=JEDI_Code_Library).

```
var
    evaluator : TEvaluator;
    value     : TFloat;
begin
    evaluator := TEvaluator.Create;
    try
        value := evaluator.Evaluate(expression);
    finally
        evaluator.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: а там корень есть

Comment: Думаю, да. Как функция Sqrt.

Comment: а если например 4+6+sqrt(7)*78

Comment: то он просто не чего не делает